# Hide the value in textbox

Tags: html

input type="text"  value="5".  I enter some text like(abc) in textbox . I needed to store text in database with id 5. So i needed value in hidden mode. How to make value in hidden mode.

Comment: which language and database are you talking about, php, asp.net, etc, databaase, mysql, anyother?

Comment: Do you mean hidden from the user? Then try type="hidden" instead of "text". What I don't get is how then will anyone be able to enter anything, like you say.

Answer (score 5):

Add an additional field to the page. In this example the first is the normal text field, the second will be hidden and will not show up:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="id" />
```

Then on the server, access both `text` and `id` to save. In PHP it would look like this:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$id   = (int)$_POST['id'];
```

**Be aware** that this is easy to tamper with on the client side, so be sure to do whatever tests are necessary on the server to make sure it wasn't hacked.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: so you know which technologies he is talking about? :)

Comment: @Sarfraz the post is tagged HTML, I can only imagine that is what he means. Since he didn't specify a server technology, I just said "In PHP it would look like..." and gave an example. The answer was the `input type=hidden`.... I think :)

Answer (score 1):

Doug Neiner's answer is the preferred method, however as an ALTERNATIVE, if your fields are dynamically generated, you could do what SO does, which is incorporate the ID# into the `id` attribute and then parse, such as `id="myText-1234` where `1234` is the id you want to pass. Then you can `split()` the id of the text box by "-" and grab the id, so long as your convention remains consistent.

Comment: Great suggestion, but it should "name" not "id".

Comment: "id" could work because it is guaranteed to be unique (so long as that is your convention). also, "name" is not a valid attribute on all html elements, where "id" is. however, for the question at hand, "name" could work just as well.

Comment: @Jason, `id` is never sent to the server. Perhaps I am reading too much into an already unclear question, but if the OP is using a `form` and a normal `input` then the only way to pass the text content *and* the id in one set as you suggest, would be to put it in the `name` attribute. That was what I meant. If he were using AJAX and pre-processing the data, then of course he could use `id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" value="" name="text" />
<input type="hidden" value="5" name="id" />
```

Then on the server, access both text and id to save. In PHP it would look like this:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
$id   = (int)$_POST['id'];
```